# Accordion checklist counter document.form[]

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 different forms with different amount of check boxes each section represents a form basiclly so when the use selects a checkbox in that section it shows how much they have checked out of the total amount for that section

HTML

```
<body class="container">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="btn1" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            <p class="count-checked-checkboxes">Name of Section 0</p>
                            <p class="numOfQuestions"></p>
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form id="form1" action="">
                            <input id="question-1" type="checkbox">
                            <label for="question-1">solution name</label>

                            <br>
                            <input id="description" type="checkbox">
                            <label for="description">solution name</label>

                            <br>
                            <input id="question-2" type="checkbox">
                            <label for="question-2">demo question</label>

                            <br>
                            <input id="question-3" type="checkbox">
                            <label for="question-3">another demo question</label>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="collapsed btn1" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                            <p class="count-checked-checkboxes">Name of Section 0</p>
                            <p class="numOfQuestions"></p>
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form id="form2" action="">
                            <input id="ques-1" type="checkbox">
                            <label for="ques-1">solution name</label>

                            <br>
                            <input id="description1" type="checkbox">
                            <label for="description1">solution name</label>

                            <br>
                            <input id="ques2" type="checkbox">
                            <label for="ques2">demo question</label>

                            <br>
                            <input id="ques3" type="checkbox">
                            <label for="ques3">another demo question</label>

                            <br>
                            <input id="ques11" type="checkbox">
                            <label for="ques11">another demo question</label>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="collapsed btn1" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                            <p class="count-checked-checkboxes">Name of Section 0</p>
                            <p class="numOfQuestions"></p>
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form id="form3" action="">
                            <input id="ques4" type="checkbox">
                            <label for="ques4">solution name</label>

                            <br>
                            <input id="description3" type="checkbox">
                            <label for="description3">solution name</label>

                            <br>
                            <input id="ques5" type="checkbox">
                            <label for="ques5">demo question</label>

                            <br>
                            <input id="ques6" type="checkbox">
                            <label for="ques6">another demo question</label>

                            <br>
                            <input id="ques44" type="checkbox">
                            <label for="ques44">another demo question</label>

                            <br>
                            <input id="ques64" type="checkbox">
                            <label for="ques64">another demo question</label>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </body>
```

jquery

```
$(function(){
        var e = document.forms[0];
        var numQuestion;
        var i;
        var formName = $(this).e;
        for(i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
            numQuestion = e.getEle**mentsByTagName('label');
            console.log(numQuestion.length);
        }

        $('#' + formName).closest('.panel-heading').find('.numOfQuestions').text('/' + e.length);

        var $checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"], #form1');

        $checkboxes.change(function(){
            var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
            $(this).closest('.panel-heading').find('.count-checked-checkboxes').text('Name of Section ' + countCheckedCheckboxes);
        });

    });
```

[my progress so far](http://jason-cameron.com/testing/ciscoDemo/)

Comment: What is the problem you're encountering?

Comment: the  <p> element that is ''numOfQuestions'' supposed to show the number of check boxes that are in that form for that section, and the <p> element with class of "count-checked-checkboxes" supposed to show how much boxes are selected per section if any are selected by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with that does the job. Commented for clarity, I think you can follow it to make whatever modifications that are necessary.

```
// --- when user changes a checkbox ---
    $(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e) {
      // --- get the form name ---
      var $form = $(this).closest('form');
      var formName = $form.attr('id');

      // --- count the checkboxes for this form ---
      var totalCheckboxes = $form.children('input[type="checkbox"]').length;

      // --- place count value in the 'numOfQuestions' p ---
      var $panel = $form.closest('.panel-default');
      $panel.find('.numOfQuestions').text('/' + totalCheckboxes);

      // --- count total checkboxes checked --- 
      var countCheckedCheckboxes = $form.children('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

      // --- place checked count in 'count-checked-checkboxes' p ---
      $panel.find('.count-checked-checkboxes').text('Name of Section '+countCheckedCheckboxes);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add change event to each input checkbox, then inside the change event, find closest `.pannel-body` then `find('input:checked')` and get the length assign to `count`.

Next just update (use closest to find the .pannel) and update the text

NOTE: closest will go up find a parent, it will not find a sibling or child.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  var count = $(this).closest('.panel-body').find('input:checked').length;
  $(this).closest('.panel').find('.count-checked-checkboxes').text(count);
  updateTotal();
});

function updateTotal(){
  var total = 0;
  $('.count-checked-checkboxes').each(function(){
    total += +$(this).text();
  });
  $('#mytotal').text(total);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="container">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div>Total: <span id="mytotal"></span></div>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="btn1" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            <p>Name of Section <span class="count-checked-checkboxes">0</span></p>
            <p class="numOfQuestions"></p>
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <form id="form1" action="">
            <input id="question-1" type="checkbox">
            <label for="question-1">solution name</label>

            <br>
            <input id="description" type="checkbox">
            <label for="description">solution name</label>

            <br>
            <input id="question-2" type="checkbox">
            <label for="question-2">demo question</label>

            <br>
            <input id="question-3" type="checkbox">
            <label for="question-3">another demo question</label>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="collapsed btn1" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
            <p>Name of Section <span class="count-checked-checkboxes">0</span></p>
            <p class="numOfQuestions"></p>
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <form id="form2" action="">
            <input id="ques-1" type="checkbox">
            <label for="ques-1">solution name</label>

            <br>
            <input id="description1" type="checkbox">
            <label for="description1">solution name</label>

            <br>
            <input id="ques2" type="checkbox">
            <label for="ques2">demo question</label>

            <br>
            <input id="ques3" type="checkbox">
            <label for="ques3">another demo question</label>

            <br>
            <input id="ques11" type="checkbox">
            <label for="ques11">another demo question</label>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="collapsed btn1" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseThree">
            <p>Name of Section <span class="count-checked-checkboxes">0</span></p>
            <p class="numOfQuestions"></p>
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <form id="form3" action="">
            <input id="ques4" type="checkbox">
            <label for="ques4">solution name</label>

            <br>
            <input id="description3" type="checkbox">
            <label for="description3">solution name</label>

            <br>
            <input id="ques5" type="checkbox">
            <label for="ques5">demo question</label>

            <br>
            <input id="ques6" type="checkbox">
            <label for="ques6">another demo question</label>

            <br>
            <input id="ques44" type="checkbox">
            <label for="ques44">another demo question</label>

            <br>
            <input id="ques64" type="checkbox">
            <label for="ques64">another demo question</label>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot, and I learned something new again, I also wanted to know how to go through the (document.forms[0]) array that is? So each section displays a number of checkboxes that are in them. ex:(6/6) if the user checks one it would be (1/6).

Comment: @JasonCameron check the updated code, few update, for Name of Section wrap the number with the class you have before, so you only need update the number count. Also added a total and function to calculate total `updateTotal`

Comment: @JasonCameron `+` in `+$(this).text()` will force the variable to become a number, otherwise you add `1+1` it is 11 as string etc.

Answer (score 0):

selector is probably the issue

```
$(this).siblings('.panel-heading').find('.count-checked-checkboxes')
```

try using parent() or closest()

Comment: replace your siblings line above, with this......  $(this).closest('.panel').find('.count-checked-checkboxes').text("Name of section " + countCheckedCheckboxes);